# fx.morph list on "click" instead of "mouseenter"

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm trying to get similar results to the fx.morph demo but on clicks instead of "mouseenter" or "mouseleave." If a list option is clicked it should morph. If another item is clicked it should morph while the original morphs to it's default state. The first part is a no brainer but so far I haven't been able to get the second part to work as desired. I tried creating a "clickOutside" event but that only works if you click somewhere that's not a list item. the new item will morph but the old one does not revert back to its original state.

Where I am so far:

```
Element.Events.outerClick = {
    base : 'click',
    condition : function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    },
    onAdd : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().addEvent('click', fn);
    },
    onRemove : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().removeEvent('click', fn);
    }
};

window.addEvent('domready', function() {
    $$('#idList LI').each(function(el) {
        el.set('morph', {
            duration: 200
        }).addEvents({
            click: el.morph.pass('.hover', el),
            outerClick: el.morph.pass('.default', el)
        });
    });

});​
```

If you want to fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JXTMa/

I reverted it back to the original mouseenter example for the sake of illustrating the original concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outerClick event will be stoped by `e.stopPropagation` so you will need to trigger that event manually with `this.getDocument().fireEvent('click')`

```
Element.Events.outerClick = {
    base : 'click',
    condition : function(event){
        event.stopPropagation();
        this.getDocument().fireEvent('click');
        return false;
    },
    onAdd : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().addEvent('click', fn);
    },
    onRemove : function(fn){
        this.getDocument().removeEvent('click', fn);
    }
};
```

Here is an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cNNjP/1/

Another way that I sometimes like is to create a class and use it as an Component. Here is an example for that: http://jsfiddle.net/kVnY4/3/

Edit: Updated the second fiddle where my component utilizes `toElement` and `store`. Check your javascript console and you will see first element retrieval from object and then object retrieval from element.

Comment: this changes the way outerClick works and may break your func if you use it elsewhere. it is also a bit expensive to add all these events to document. you can do the whole thing in CSS with :checked and transitions as well :)

Comment: I don't know what else to say other than that's perfect! I'll have to sit down with both examples when I've had some sleep so I can digest it all and retain it but I think I see what you like about the second example. Thanks a million :)

Comment: I definitely see your point, Dimitar. For this specific purpose I know for sure nothing will be broken but I'll probably use the suggested alternative to start getting into the habit of doing it that way to avoid any future breakage. :)